# Where should a *sqlx.DB object be save for a cobra application?

Tags: go, sqlx, go-cobra

I have a cobra project which accesses database using `sqlx` package, and the command has sub-commands. The cobra related code is in the `cmd` folder/subpackage and the DB related code is in the `db` folder/subpackage.

I would like to have package db to have a factory function

```
func NewDB() *sqlx.DB
```

which is called somewhere from the `cmd` package. But I am not sure where to call it and how to make it available to all sub-commands.

One idea is to have a global variable in the `cmd` package, and initialize it either in `root.go`'s `init()` or `rootCmd`'s `PersistentPreRun`. Is it bad to use global variable in this case?

If I don't use global variable, 
one possibility is to have the sub-commands call `db.NewDB()`. Somehow it doesn't feel very nice this way either.

I find it nicer to call `db.NewDB()` once in `cmd` package, probably in `root.go`. But where should I save the DB handle such that sub-commands can use it?

Comment: You should call NewDB if, when, and where you need it. init is the worst choice by far. You don't want to establish a database connection if --help is given, for instance.

Comment: The information that you are using cobra  is not relevant here. You could also create your app with the flag package. It would be helpful what your app does and how long does it run. If it is a server you should also check if the connection is still alive, if it just runs for loading data into a file and quits after that you just call NewDB when you need it.

Comment: @apxp There is no long-running server for this app. It is a command line client to query db. Thank you both for the good points and I will call `NewDB` wherever it's needed